# How does gstreamer's h265parse element transform the buffer?

Tags: gstreamer, h.265

I am trying to feed video into an `rtph265pay` element from an `appsrc` so that the gstreamer-rtsp-server framework can serve up a stream.

If I give the framework a pipeline like `appsrc name=hevc ! h265parse ! rtph265pay name=pay0` then it works OK.  If I remove the `h265parse` and call `setCaps()` on the `appsrc` with the parsed version of `video/x-h265,stream-format=hvc1,alignment=au,parsed=true` the framework exits the entire application without an obvious error message. (after some more experiments it is highly likely it is crashing because it is trying to allocate an astounding amount of memory and fails.  I have to deactivate all my swaps to make sure my machine remains interactive)

```
** Message: activated deep-notify
0:00:03.860349781 11247 0x7f46cc0294a0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3902:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<appsrc1:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:03.860568982 11247 0x7f46cc029770 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3902:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<hevc:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0: do-retransmission = false
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstAppSrc:hevc.GstPad:src: caps = "video/x-h265\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)hvc1\,\ alignment\=\(string\)au\,\ parsed\=\(boolean\)true"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstRtpH265Pay:pay0.GstPad:sink: caps = "video/x-h265\,\ stream-format\=\(string\)hvc1\,\ alignment\=\(string\)au\,\ parsed\=\(boolean\)true"
trying to initialize log file /var/tmp/artillery-turtle-latency-2018-02-27_16.txt
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstRtpH265Pay:pay0.GstPad:src: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0.GstGhostPad:src_0: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:send_rtp_sink_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad2: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0/GstRtpSession:rtpsession0.GstPad:send_rtp_src: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstRtpBin:rtpbin0.GstGhostPad:send_rtp_src_0: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstTee:tee0.GstTeePad:src_0: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:sink: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:src: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:src: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstAppSink:appsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstAppSink:appsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = "application/x-rtp\,\ media\=\(string\)video\,\ payload\=\(int\)96\,\ clock-rate\=\(int\)90000\,\ encoding-name\=\(string\)H265\,\ ssrc\=\(uint\)2832925622\,\ timestamp-offset\=\(uint\)619621697\,\ seqnum-offset\=\(uint\)9508"
```

I have rigged test pipelines with an `identity silent=false` on either side of the `h265parse` to try to gain an understanding of what it is doing, but I'm not sure which difference is the important one.

```
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (51472 bytes, dts: none, pts: 0:00:06.875000000, duration: 0:00:00.041666000, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00000000 , meta: none) 0x7f53dc0637c0
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (12665 bytes, dts: none, pts: 0:00:06.916666000, duration: 0:00:00.041666000, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00000000 , meta: none) 0x7f53dc0bcd90
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstIdentity:identity0: last-message = chain   ******* (identity0:sink) (12583 bytes, dts: none, pts: 0:00:06.958333000, duration: 0:00:00.041666000, offset: -1, offset_end: -1, flags: 00000000 , meta: none) 0x7f53dc071bf0
```

versus

```
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstIdentity:identity1: last-message = chain   ******* (identity1:sink) (51473 bytes, dts: none, pts: 0:00:06.833333000, duration: none, offset: 2722840, offset_end: -1, flags: 00002000 delta-unit , meta: none) 0x7f53dc071ae0
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstIdentity:identity1: last-message = chain   ******* (identity1:sink) (12666 bytes, dts: none, pts: 0:00:06.875000000, duration: none, offset: 2774312, offset_end: -1, flags: 00002000 delta-unit , meta: none) 0x7f53dc10e400
/GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstBin:bin0/GstIdentity:identity1: last-message = chain   ******* (identity1:sink) (12584 bytes, dts: none, pts: 0:00:06.916666000, duration: none, offset: 2786977, offset_end: -1, flags: 00002000 delta-unit , meta: none) 0x7f53dc1119b0
```

The differences I can see include:

- it adds a byte (not sure why, or what)
- it shifts the PTS by -1/24 ( a single frame period)
- it removes the duration
- it sets the offset to a value which seems to be the sum of the post-modification byte counts (not that surprising)
- it sets a flag which is labeled as delta-unit

How can I adjust my buffers that I send to the `appsrc` so that I no longer need the overhead of `h265parse` ?  I'm already very very close, but the docs for the `h265parse` element can be described as somewhere between thin and nonexistent (there isn't even a documentation link for the element in the gst-plugins-bad element list).

Comment: After a few more experiments I have discovered that if I route h265parse into a file it appears to be formatted like a sample in an MP4 mdat atom (32-bit length code followed by the NAL unit without the 000001 Annex.B start code).  But if I format my samples like this, the rtp payloader still crashes while allocating astoundingly large quantities of RAM.

Comment: `h265parse` supports various formats. it converts depending on the downstream's element requirements. It depends whether you have full AU's, NALs and or byte-streams or avc samples.. Look at the caps of `rtph265pay`. It takes either hvc1/au or nal/au/byte-stream. You need to communicate your desired format to `rtph265pay` as well..

Comment: I have also discovered that it sets some rather extensive caps on its source sink: `video/x-h265, stream-format=(string)hev1, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)6.2, tier=(string)main, profile=(string)main, codec_data=(buffer)010160000000800000000000baf000fcfdf8f800001303200001001940010c02ffff0160000003008000000300000300ba00002c0921000100214201020160000003008000000300000300ba0000a001e020078168b92472880080220001000a4401c1620f0820224c90` .  I'm going to have to hunt down the layout of that decoder config record.

Comment: I think that's the `hvcC` box data from the MP4 file specification.